# How to read character in whitespace language

Tags: haskell, input, whitespace-language

I am having tough time to understand how characters reading works in Whitespace. I was able to run Hello World program. But now I try to read just one character from user and then print it on standard output.
I am getting no errors, everything compiles fine but character doesnt appear on output. I've tried to debug it a little but its really hard in whitespace and I believe that it doesn't print nothing because the value that I read from user is 0 (or null).

Here is how I read the character (I believe its the correct way)

```
start          















end
```

And here the SSCCE of printing out (this should work because its almost the same an it was in Hello World project.

```
start           


















end
```

I am using Whitespace 0.3 and Haskell Compiler version 5.02

Comment: Apparently stackoverflow does not preserve spaces.

Comment: This is one of the funniest questions I have ever seen on SO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's some example code that gets a character, stores it in the heap, immediately retrieves it and prints it:

```
Command                 Description     Stack   Heap
=======================================================
space space space lf    push 0          0
space lf space          duplicate       0 0
tab lf tab space        get character   0       h[0]=c
tab tab tab             retrieve        c       h[0]=c
tab lf space space      put character           h[0]=c
lf lf lf                exit
```